# XML convertion to DF in Python

Tags: python, xml, dataframe

I am opening large xml file, where i am getting some results using this code:

```
import os
import xml.etree.ElementTree as et
base_path=os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))

xml_file=os.path.join(base_path,'my xml path file')
tree=et.parse(xml_file)
root=tree.getroot()

for child in root:
    for element in child:
        print (element.tag,':',element.text)
        for one in element:
            print(one.tag,':',one.text)
```

example of result:

```
code_one : a
value_one : blue
default: 3

code_one : a
value_one : black
default: 12

code_one : b
value_one : green
default: 4

Rte:
Rte:
```

To this point everything is clear and fine, but i want to save this output which i am printing to data frame, or if this will be a problem , to file and then i will open this file and save as DF.

I need to convert output to looks like this one:

```
code_one, value_one, default
a, blue, 3       
a, black, 12
b, green, 4
```

thanks in advice

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
header = ["code_one", "value_one", "default"]
vals =[]
for child in root:
    for element in child:
        if header == [element.tag] + [x.tag for x in element]:
            vals.append([element.text] + [x.text for x in element]
print(", ".join(header))
for v in vals:
    print(", ".join(v))
```

I couldn't verify the code above works since you didn't provide an example file, but it should. Does this help?

Comment: hey @Felix i am receiving :    ` print(", ".join(*v))
TypeError: join() takes exactly one argument (2 given) ` , please note that in DF i need to add only `code_one, value_one & default` not other data like `Rte:`

Comment: thanks,in 6th line You forgot about ' ) ' at the end, this time i am receiving `Process finished with exit code 0` only, sorry that i cant post source data here, but its restricted, and its tooo large

Answer (score 0):

this solved my problem:
i have wrote output to the file, and then i have opened using pandas in dataframe
this is how to save the output:

```
f=open('file.txt','w')
for child in root:
    for element in child:
        f.write(str(element.tag)+':'+str(element.text))
        for one in element:
            f.write(str(one.tag)+':'+str(one.text))
f.close()
```